# How to make this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I´m trying to learn ajax, sitting here sinse 3 hours and trying to understand what I need to make it run.

I´m using it on Scriptly with Xampp.

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>Titel</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ajax Example!</title>

    <script src="js\jquery/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            //alert("hello");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/inde.php",
                    data: {
                        myName: "durgesh technoclass"
                    },
                    success: function(output){
                        alert(output);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    <button id="btnSubmit">Click me !</button>
</form>
```

I even watched a tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn-pvdpXNw8) and copied all the code from there.
The rating of the tutorial is good, the code seems to work for him, but why doesn´t it work for me ?! I don´t understand that.

The Jquery works, but ajax doesn´t. The Script just reloads the page and displays nothing.

Please help.

**Edit:**

May it be that it doesn´t work, because xampp doesn´t run an actual server ?

On request, here´s the code of the `"inde.php"`:

```
<?php
    echo "Welcome from Server";
?>
```

**Edit 2:**
Solution:
I messed up the path of the inde.php. 
Just fixed it.

It works but there´s a mistake in the code. It had been fixed by [Tanvir Ahmad Sohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4995195/tanvir-ahmad-sohan). You can find his fix in his answer down there.

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery is loading? Check your console because `<script src="js\jquery/jquery.js">` looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: Name of the php file also looks suspicious. Is it inde.php or index.php?

Comment: Any errors or warning in the browsers console?

Comment: I flagged a few very rude/offensive comments. Please keep a civil tongue. You could get suspended for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            //alert("hello");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/inde.php",
                    data: {
                        myName: "durgesh technoclass"
                    },
                    success: function(output){
                        alert(output);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

As your button is inside a form, when you click the button, form is being submitted to the same page, so it just reloads. To prevent this from happening use `preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour.

Comment: Your code is in `htdocs` folder right? And please post your `inde.php` file.

Comment: No.. Calm down... :P... Open debugging tool, go to network monitor and check what status the ajax request returns...

Comment: If you're on Firefox press F12 to open debugging console. Then click on 'Network'. After that click the button of your page and check the value under status column for `inde.php`

Comment: That means your request can't find the file. Are you running on a server or clicking the html file to open it on browser? No message on console?

Comment: What's the name of the folder? Is `inde.php` also in that folder?